# What happens when a card with undying dies that has a +1/+1 counter put on it by something other that undying?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, I have a *Howlgeist* that I enchanted with *Oath of Ancient Wood* so it has a +1/+1 counter on it, when it dies does it not come back because of the +1/+1 counter even though it wasn't put there by Undying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undying doesn't care how the +1/+1 counter got there. Undying won't trigger.

Conversely, if Undying previously placed a +1/+1 counter on a permanent, but the counter got removed [somehow](http://magiccards.info/som/en/63.html) before the permanent died a second time, Undying will trigger and bring the card back a second time.

Comment: It's important to note that putting a -1/-1 on to remove the +1/+1 can't be what actually causes leathal damage or 0 toughness. If it is, the state based action check will kill it with both counters still on it, so neither undying nor persist will trigger.

Comment: @Michael Snook, Indeed.